# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://localhost/test/1659071138.jpg' for python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://localhost/test/1659071138.jpg'

take a screenshot from localhost api and save localhost  perticular folder
i am trying to capture screenshot live browser page screenshot per seconds
im trying to make application that take a screen shot from currently visible screen,
i have tries with below code,
but when im run my code i got below error,

Error :
please help me on this, what i do wrong here, i don't understand.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import urllib.request
#import requests
import os
#import mysql.connector
import schedule

import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from functools import partial
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import pyautogui as pg
from datetime import datetime


ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('400x300')


f = ('Times', 14)



def validateLogin():
   user = register_name.get()
   passw = register_pwd.get()

   return


def screenshot():
 
   random = int(time.time())
   print("Taking screenshot...")
   #ss = pg.screenshot(filename,"w")
   
   #imgURL = "http://localhost/test/"  + str(random) + ".jpg"
   #urllib.request.urlretrieve("GET",imgURL)
   #url = "http://localhost/test/" + str(random) + ".jpg"
   #req = requests.request("GET",url)
   filename = r"http://localhost/test/" + str(random) + ".jpg"
   
   imgURL = "http://localhost/test/image/mobile6.jpg"
   urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgURL, "D:/test/image/"+ str(random) + ".jpg")
   ss = pg.screenshot(filename)   

   def main():
     schedule.every().second.do(screenshot)
 

     while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(5)
    
      
      
       # time.stop(5)
   if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
   


def hide_window( ):
   # hiding the tkinter window while taking the screenshot
   
   ws.withdraw()
   ws.after(1, screenshot)

 
  


# Add a Label widget
   #Label(ws, text="Click the Button to Take the Screenshot", font=('Times New Roman', 18, 'bold')).pack(pady=10)

# Create a Button to take the screenshots
#button = Button(ws, text="Take Screenshot", font=('Aerial 11 bold'), background="#aa7bb1", foreground="white", command=hide_wsdow)
#button.pack(pady=20)





#second wsdow
def open_win():

   new= Toplevel(ws)
 
   new.title("Newsdow")
   
   
   #Create a Label in New window
   Label(new, font=('Helvetica 17 bold')).grid(row=0, column=1) 
   button = Button(new, text="Take Screenshot", command=hide_window)
   button.grid(row=4, column=1) 
   new.destroy
  
 
   print("username entered :", register_name.get())
   print("password entered :", register_pwd.get())
   
 
 

 

 
   #return
 
right_frame = Frame(
    ws, 
    bd=2, 
    bg='#CCCCCC',
    relief=SOLID, 
    padx=10, 
    pady=10,
    
    )




#main window

#Create a label
#Label(win, text= "Click the below button to Open a New Window", font= ('Helvetica 17 bold')).pack(pady=30)
#Create a button to open a New Window
#username label and text entry box


Label(
    right_frame, 
    text="Enter Name", 
    bg='#CCCCCC',
    font=f
    ).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)



Label(
    right_frame, 
    text="Enter Password", 
    bg='#CCCCCC',
    font=f
    ).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)



register_name = Entry(
    right_frame, 
    font=f
    )




register_pwd = Entry(
    right_frame, 
    font=f,
    show='*'
)
validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, register_name, register_pwd)

register_btn = Button(
    right_frame, 
    width=15, 
    text='Login', 
    font=f, 
    relief=SOLID,
    cursor='hand2',
    command=hide_window
)


register_name.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)

register_pwd.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)

register_btn.grid(row=7, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)
right_frame.pack(
    expand=YES)



ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error obviously tells you that you cannot save the screenshot to a URL using `pyautogui.screenshot()`.

Comment: i have use code given by you but this not work